# LINQ expression to get modified objects

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of addresses whereas an address is defined as follows:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Based on a previous call I have a list of tuples whereas a tuple consists of the address id and the modified date.

```
e.g. List<Tuple<int, DateTime>>
```

Now I would like to get all addresses with the corresponding id but only if they have been modified.

I have converted the list of tuples to an int array containing the ids and a dictionary whereas the id is the key and the modified date is the value.

```
int[] ids;
Dictionary<int, DateTime> dates;
```

The following is sufficient to get all addresses with the corresponding id.

```
addressList.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id));
```

Unfortunately the following is not possible:

> Exception: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

```
addressList.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id) && dates[a.Id] < a.ModifiedDate);
```

The problem could be solved by a loop but I'm searching a more elegant solution.

```
List<Address> modifiedAddressList = new List<Address>();
foreach (Address a in addressList)
{
    if (a.ModifiedDate > dates[a.Id]) modifiedAddressList.Add(a);
}
```

Comment: *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method...* which method?

Comment: You forgot .ToList() at the end of each Where

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I think that's his mistake, it's the `indexer` `dates[a.Id]`.

Comment: @KingKing yep, me too. But he left most important part of exception out of question :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky and the underlying method is `get_Item(Int32)`, that's it :)

Comment: @KingKing exactly. I have edited the exception message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have a dictionary with some information in your application, and some current dates in your database.  You need to get both in the same place in order to compare the two data sets.  This means either getting the information in your dictionary over to the database, or bringing the data from the database back to your application before you do the comparison.

If you want to send your data to the database it needs to be done through SQL; your database can't just run any old C# code, which is what you seem to be trying to do and why it's not working.

The "simpler" solution probably is to do what you seem to like less, namely pulling the data from the database and then filtering it within your application.  The other option would be to upload the data you have in your dictionary to a temp table and then JOIN the two tables together.

You can do the first option in a bit more LINQ-esk way if you'd like though:

```
addressList.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(a => dates[a.Id] < a.ModifiedDate);
```

The `AsEnumerable` call will ensure that the subsequent methods are performed in your application, not translated to SQL.  The `Contains` check can be translated into a IN clause in SQL, so it should be *before* the `AsEnumerable` call so it's done on the DB end.

Comment: Great answer I really appreciate it! Do you know if there is a limit the contains method can handle?

Comment: @Moo A few thousand items, I believe.  It's actually the limitation of the DB that is usually hit first.  Most databases don't support IN clauses with more than 2-5 thousand items.  If you pass that limit you have the same problem again; either do both within your application (i.e. move the `AsEnumerable` up) or upload that information to a temp table.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here, is that LinqToEntities has no understanding of your dictionary - and how to turn that into a database query.

You have a few options:

1. Loop over every item (as you suggested)
2. Pass in the Ids of the modified records
3. Download the whole dataset to the client (using a ToList()) and then using your dictionary approach

Option #3 is really easy - if you're not dealing with a large dataset:

```
addressList
    .Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(dates[a.Id] < a.ModifiedDate);
```